# Replacing Part of an iFrame URL based on User Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I would like to have a text box and submit button with an iframe below.

When a user types something into the text box, I would like multiple iFrames to load using that query.

For example, if a user types "Cars", I would want to have 3 iFrames show up such as Bing, Yahoo, and Google searches for cars.

Not all URLs will have the same structure

For example one may be "google.com/cars" while another may be "bing.com/search/cars"

This is a fictional example, but I hope it helps make the point clear

Here are some of the URLs I want to modify by switching out "TICK" with whatever is in the user input field

```
http://finance.yahoo.com/q/h?s=TICK+Headlines

http://www.otcmarkets.com/stock/TICK/filings
```

Those links will be inside different iFrames with specific margins and formatting

```
<div style="border: 3px solid rgb(201, 0, 1); overflow: hidden; margin: 15px auto; max-width:  736px;">
```

Comment: This wont work, Google doesn't allow itself to get iframed

Answer (score 0):

First:

> This wont work, Google doesn't allow itself to get iframed

But, I can answer how to change the iframes:

```
// From the page that has the iframe
document.getElementById('IdOfTheIframe_1').href = "google.com/#q="+your_value;
// From the iframe itself:
window.location = "google.com/#q="+your_value;
```

Comment: Im not trying to iframe google. It was just an example. I added more info to the description. Im not an experienced coder so any help is appreciated

Comment: I've provided to pieces of code in my answer, both will do what you want, it just depends where you're at in the page (see the comment).

Answer (score 0):

Javascript allows you to set html attributes so you could use this code

```
document.getElementById('idofyouriframe').setAttribute("href","newUrl");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few different ways of doing this, but here's a couple

1. You already have 3 `<IFRAME>`s on page, and you just need to set their document location (i.e, `SRC` attribute)
2. You create the `IFRAME` element on the fly using Javascript and then set its location to the appropriate URL.

Assuming your textbox `<input>` field is inside a `<form>` element, you can set your form's `onSubmit` to call a Javascript function that does it.

Here's an example using the first method:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<SCRIPT>
    function loadIframes(){
        document.getElementById('if1').href = 'BING URL PREFIX'+document.getElementById('textfield').value;
        document.getElementById('if2').href = 'YAHOO  PREFIX'+document.getElementById('textfield').value;
        document.getElementById('if3').href = 'GOOGLE  PREFIX'+document.getElementById('textfield').value;
    }
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FORM onsubmit="loadIframes()">
    <INPUT type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield"/>
    <INPUT type="submit" value="Search"/>
</FORM>
<IFRAME id="if1" width="300" height="300"/>
<IFRAME id="if2" width="300" height="300"/>
<IFRAME id="if3" width="300" height="300"/>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but this didn't work for me. I added some more information to my description, maybe that will help. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I see you are using `<div>` tags. Do these div tags have iframes inside them? You can't load a page directly into a div (well, you could technically parse and set the innerHTML of the div to the page's content, but that's no what we are trying to do).